# Struggling to understand a django class based view code

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I was reading the docs for the *django class based view* when I encountered a code that I couldn't really understand. If someone could explain the "**get**" part it would be really helpful.

**here is the view code**

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import View

from .forms import MyForm

class MyFormView(View):
    form_class = MyForm
    initial = {'key': 'value'}
    template_name = 'form_template.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(initial=self.initial)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # <process form cleaned data>
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/')

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

What's the "**initial**" for ? And how the get function is contributing to this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `get` function renders the form, i.e. produces HTML of the form. When given a dictionary of [initial values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#initial), then even on the first visit, the form will already be filled — with the initial values. Otherwise it would be empty.

The class variable `initial` is merely storing the initial values, so they can be used by the get function. You *could* put the variable also in the `get` method or omit it entirely:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = self.form_class(initial={'key': 'value'})
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

(Would not do it though, as the initial values are then slightly less visible, and they really are important.)

Also, have a look at the documentation regarding [bound and unbound forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/api/#bound-and-unbound-forms), to understand the difference between initial and default values.

Answer (score 2):

`initial = {'key': 'value'}`
is a place to set some default values for the form.
`self.form_class(initial=self.initial)`
uses those defaults to fill the form when there is a GET request.

Comment: So it works kind of like an else? if the form is valid return ... else it requests data from the initial, is it how it works?

Comment: When a GET request is sent for the associated url for that view, it uses the get method.
When a form is submitted usually you're doing a POST, and that would use the post method.  The post method does the checking for whether the form is valid.